# Import contact from Address book to label

Tags: iphone, sdk, contacts

Is there any way to import a contact field(name, mobile phone, address) in a label?
(for iPhone app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using the [AddressBook framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH1-SW1).

Apple has instructions on how to retrieve contacts from your address book [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Chapters/DirectInteraction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744-CH6-SW1).

Once you have retrieved a contact as an `ABRecordRef`, you can use the method `ABRecordCopyValue(ABRecordRef record, ABPropertyID property)` to get string values.

For example, to get a phone number, you could say (assuming curPerson is an already obtained `ABRecordRef`):

```
NSString *mobilePhone = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(curPerson, kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel);
```